# Jquery lightbox issue?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

my website in [www.codtelevision.com/live](http://www.codtelevision.com/live)

Click the link. For some reason, the page expands, then when you close it gets smaller. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your #bkimg element.  It is positioned absolutely with a min-width: of 50% and a min-height of 50%.  So, this image is going to expand to 50% (width/height respectively) of the window width.  You can remove the percentages and the background will stop "expanding".  However, this will cause your element to move off screen when your browser window is adjusted.

Here is a fix I'll propose.

1)  Completely remove the #bkimg element from your HTML.
2)  Re-do your body element with styles to reflect exactly what you want.  In this case, I'll change your body tag to this:

```
body {
  background: url(wpimages/wp6a390e39.png) top center no-repeat;
}
```

This will cause your background to remain in the center of the browser and will not "grow" or "shrink" depending on window size.  Furthermore, this will present additional issues with your layout.  Almost all of your entire page structure is based off elements that are positioned absolutely.  This will be a problem with smaller browser sizes, smaller resolutions, or people who like to browse without expanding the full browser window (most OSX users do this).  You will need to adjust your layout accordingly to flow with the browser rather than having elements position absolutely.